# How to return ffmepg processed output file and pass it to another function? using python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, speech-recognition

I want to convert video to audio using ffmpeg and I also want to return that audio file and pass it on to another function which generates text from that audio. But when I pass 'audio' to function error shows file not found..

```
def extract_audio(f):
print("processing", f)
inFile = f
outFile = f[:-3] + "wav"
cmd = "ffmpeg -i {} -vn  -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f wav {}".format(inFile, outFile)
os.popen(cmd)
print(outFile)
print("Audio is ready to use..")
return outFile

def audio_to_text(audio):
r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 4000
with sr.WavFile(open(audio)) as source:  # use "test.wav" as the audio source
    audio_source = r.record(source)  # extract audio data from the file
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_source)
try:
    print(text)  # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:  # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
audio = extract_audio(filename)
audio_to_text(audio)
```

Comment: I get this error: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x000002445A15D1D0>

Comment: this isn't an error, this is the object representation being printed. It means that it worked. but I think I misread your question. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that `os.popen()` returns a handle on a process output and returns to the caller, leaving the program running in the background.

So when you're calling your audio post-processing, `ffmpeg` hasn't finished to run yet/maybe not even started creating the audio file (race condition between your process and the `ffmpeg` subprocess)

You have to *wait* for the command to end. I'd use `subprocess.check_call` for that, and a *list* of arguments instead of composing the command as string (which has to be split, possibly with quoting/space errors):

```
cmd = ["ffmpeg","-i",inFile,"-vn","-ac","2","-ar","44100","-ab","320k","-f","wav",outFile]
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

when `check_call` returns (without raising an exception), it means that `ffmpeg` finished creating the output file. You can safely try to open it for reading now.

Answer (score 1):

Does the file exist? I would suggest using `exit_state = os.system(cmd)` instead, and verify that `exit_state` is zero before returning `outFile`. With this you make sure that the `ffmpeg` command has finished successfully.

Comment: that'd probably work. even if the explanation isn't given why OP current code doesn't work.